# How to declare a property change listener in ScalaFX properly?

Tags: scala, scalafx

Using [this code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalafx-users/xTCv1rB102k/OOlVuOIUPmQJ) as an example I have written the following to track changes of a slider and put the result into the "speed: Int" variable:

```
speedSlider.valueProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener[Number] {
  @Override
  def changed(o: ObservableValue[_ <: Number], oldVal: Number, newVal: Number) {
    speed = newVal.intValue()
  }
})
```

But it causes an error:

```
wrong number of type arguments for scalafx.beans.value.ObservableValue, should be 2
  def changed(o: ObservableValue[_ <: Number], oldVal: Number, newVal: Number) {
```

If I change `ObservableValue[_ <: Number]` to `ObservableValue[_ <: Number, _ <: Number]` this error disappears but another emerges:

```
object creation impossible, since method changed in trait ChangeListener of type (x$1: javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue[_ <: Number], x$2: Number, x$3: Number)Unit is not defined
speedSlider.valueProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener[Number] {
                                          ^
```

Any ideas?

Update: I have resolved the errors by replacing `ObservableValue` (which was being resolved into the ScalaFX version which I don't really understand) with `javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue`. It compiles and throws no errors now, but still doesn't work - the code is never invoked.

Comment: Incidentally, in _Scala_, you should prefer the **override** modifier over the **@Override** annotation. _Scala_ is not _Java_. I'm not even sure the latter will work as you expect if is actually required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/scalafx/source/browse/scalafx/src/main/scala/scalafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.scala) I see you don't need to pass a `ChangeListener` but simply an anonymous function with the same signature as the `onChange` method

```
speedSlider.valueProperty.addListener{ (o: javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue[_ <: Number], oldVal: Number, newVal: Number) =>
  speed = newVal.intValue
}
```

Otherwise the method will expect a `javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener`

I hope this solves the issue.

Comment: Well. This works (while the ChangeListener version I've written does not) but only as soon as I specify the types: `(o, oldVal, newVal)` does not compile, I had to replace it with `(o: javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue[_ <: Number], oldVal: Number, newVal: Number)`.

Comment: I suspected so, but being hard replying from the tablet I tried to be as concise as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else encounters this problem. With Scala 3 the following works:

```scala
        rotate.statusProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener[Animation.Status]() {
            override def changed(observableValue: ObservableValue[ _ <: Animation.Status],
                                oldValue: Animation.Status, newValue: Animation.Status) = {
                text2.setText("Was - " + oldValue + ", Now - " + newValue)

            }
        })
```

Notice that the anonymous class must have the type parameter fully defined, but not the overridden method.